# I have to download a large number of big size images and show in table view?

Tags: ios

I am getting memory warning when loading large images, i have to cache the images also so that if the user will scroll up that image should be present. I am using SDWebImage Library.
                                                                                                          cell!.productImageView?.sd_setImageWithURL(url)

Comment: show your code in which you are loading images in uiimageview

Comment: cell!.productImageView?.sd_setImageWithURL(url)

Answer (score 1):

According to your scenario I have two suggestions:
1. Generally recommended is that we can upload small size images on server so that we can avoid memory problems. A thumbnail or a small dimension sized image is considered if we are showing the images in a `UITableView`.
However we can show larger image when we tap on a certain small image in `UITableView` and go to a **detail** view controller.
2. Secondly you can download the images and resize them and then use `NSCache` class to cache them rather using `SDWebImage`. As in your case `imageWithContentsOfFile` can't be used because you are downloading the images from some URL.
However after download you can use `imageWithContentsOfFile` or you can resize images and use your own `NSCache`.

Comment: Can you provide any tutorial i have tried by compressing images and saving in an Array but i have to do it asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for display image on image view .UIImage imageNamed is maintain cache itself.

Comment: cell!.productImageView?.sd_setImageWithURL(url)

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code.

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"png"]];
```

This will helpful to you for manage memory consumptions.

Comment: i have to download image and than i have to show and it should be asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
NSString *thumbnailImage = objectname.thumbnailUrl;

    [cell.productImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbnailImage]];
```